# making bar-code system in vb.net 2008

Tags: vb.net

I have made some real time systems (softwares). Now I want to make an system (software) in vb.net 2008 which reads an bar-code saves the data in the database (SQL Server database). I am very new in making these types of system, thus i would like your help of making an system using bar-code scanner through vb.net 2008. Specific to my question I will require all the steps for creating an bar-code system through vb.net 2008. I am waiting for your reply.
Thanking you,

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to be a whole lot more specific, as there is no one answer to "how to make barcode system".

Are you attempting to read barcodes that are on physical objects through barcode scanner hardware?  Do you already have the scanner?  How does it work?

Are you trying to read barcodes from images?

We're not going to be able to provide step-by-step instructions on how to make a system that hasn't been at all described, nor provide step-by-step instructions on building an entire system.  If you provide some more details about specific problems, you can likely get help with those specific questions.